# commandLink reRender doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandlink

I am trying to reRender a block after the user clicks a commandLink that updates an object. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<apex:page controller=“ServiceSubscription" tabStyle="Account">

<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Details">
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem  dataStyle="width: 30%">
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <h2>IDs Associated With Account</h2>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!setUserForVisualForce}" reRender="accountData">
                                    111
                                    <apex:param assignTo="{!visualForceUserId}" name="Id" value="111"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width: 70%" id=“accountData">
                    <h2>Account Data</h2>

                    <table class="list">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="headerRow">
                                <th>Account ID</th>
                                <th>Subscription ID</th>
                                <th>Max Records Available</th>
                                <th>Current Records Used</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="dataRow">
                                <td class="dataCell">{!userForVisualForce.id}</td>
                                <td class="dataCell">{!userForVisualForce.subscriptionId}</td>
                                <td class="dataCell">{!userForVisualForce.subscriptionMaxRecords}</td>
                                <td class="dataCell">{!userForVisualForce.currentRecords}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

```
public class ServiceSubscription {
    public ServiceAccount visualForceUser = new ServiceAccount();
    public String visualForceUserId {get; set;}

    public PageReference setUserForVisualForce() {
        if (this.visualForceUserId != null) {            
            this.visualForceUser    = this.get(Integer.valueOf(this.visualForceUserId));
            this.visualForceUserId  = null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public ServiceAccount getUserForVisualForce() {
        return this.visualForceUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly your issue is

Comment: When you remove the `rerender` attribute and add an `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag to the page - does it show you any errors in the messages output?

Comment: @SantanuBoral nothing happens once I click the link. I can see in the debug logs that the setSubscriptionId() line runs, but the table doesn't reflect the change.

Comment: @MarkPond it does not show any error messages when I do that, nope.

Answer (score 1):

`AssignTo` attribute looks for the property defined in Controller. It will not assign object's instance value directly from it.

That is you are trying to assign value to `visualForceUser.id` by `assignTo` which will not work.

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!setUserForVisualForce}" reRender="accountData">
    111
    <apex:param assignTo="{!userid}" name="Id" value="111"/>
    <apex:param assignTo="{!subscriptionId}" name="subscriptionId" value=""/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

Controller

```
public String subscriptionId {get;set;}
public String userid {get;set;}
```

Comment: I changed it to work this way. And I can definitively say the now my `this.visualForceUser` variable is being assigned correctly and the values are right (used System.debug directly after the assignment to confirm). However, it still doesn't reRender the `accountData` section

Comment: can you post your updated code in the question, I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

I have seen like this before most of the time **`<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`**  failed Re-render.

Alternative you can do  have **`<apex:outputPanel>`** inside  and render **`<apex:outputPanel>`** . i have tried similar to your code ,following code is working fine.

**VisualForce Page :**

```
<apex:page controller="cntr190500" >

    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Details">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width: 30%">
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <h2>IDs Associated With Account</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!displayMsg}" reRender="accountData" value="{!msg}" >                                                            
                                    <apex:param assignTo="{!msg}" name="msg" value="msg from visulforce"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width: 70%" >
                    <apex:outputPanel id="accountData" >
                    <h2>Account Data</h2>

                    <table class="list">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="headerRow">
                                <th>Account ID</th>
                                <th>Subscription ID</th>
                                <th>Max Records Available</th>
                                <th>Current Records Used</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="dataRow">
                                <td class="dataCell">{!msg}</td>
                                <td class="dataCell">{!msg}</td>
                                <td class="dataCell">{!msg}</td>
                                <td class="dataCell">{!msg}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller : cntr190500**

public class cntr190500 {

```
    public string msg{get;set;}
    public cntr190500(){
        msg='click here';
    }
    public void displayMsg(){
        msg='New message from apex';
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work :(

Comment: @Kenyon i have updated answers, it is working fine with me.

Comment: Can you share the controller you used? It isn't working for me :/

Comment: @Kenyon I have updated code what i have tried similar to your code.

Comment: @Kenyon i can't try with your  controller, because your controller is incomplete understand fully .

Comment: Finally got it working. I think it was line 2 of my controller.